# Hyphenation not working properly when text is prefixed with \textbackslash

Tags: hyphenat

First question: what causes text, when prefixed with `\textbackslash`, not to be hyphenated?

Second question: what is the difference between packages `hyphenation` and `hyphenat` - which is the one I am using in the `MWE`. Browsing through `CTAN` for an answer is like getting lost in the woods.

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 24 Jan 2019
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations,log-functions]{expl3}
\usepackage{MyHyphenationDefinitions}
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
\noindent
\textbf{filler.......................text} thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthefenceandalmostgothislegcaught

\noindent
\textbf{filler.......................text} \textbackslash thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthefenceandalmostgothislegcaught

\end{document}


% filename: MyHyphenationDefinitions.sty
\ProvidesExplPackage{MyHyphenationDefinitions}{}{}{}

\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}  %  enables normal as well as tt text to be hyphenated
\hyphenation{the-quick-brown-fox-jumped-over-the-fence-and-al-most-got-his-leg-caught}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, package `hyphenat` is a little bit old and I suggest to use package `fontenc` instead to get a better hyphenation. The advantage is that you get rid of the several warnings package `[htt]{hyphenat}` generates as already mentioned in the documentation:

[image: docu hyphenat]

I added package `showframe` to visualize the resulting typing area and margins of your document. It helps us to see if the hyphenation is inside the typing area or not.

Please see the following changed mwe

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 24 Jan 2019
%=======================
%\usepackage[check-declarations,log-functions]{expl3}
%\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}  % <==================== enables normal as well as tt text to be hyphenated
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <============================================
\usepackage{showframe} % <==============================================
\hyphenation{the-quick-brown-fox-jumped-over-the-fence-and-al-most-got-his-leg-caught}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\textbf{filler.......................text} 
thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthefenceandalmostgothislegcaught

\noindent
\textbf{filler......................text} % <=========================== one blank deleted!
\textbackslash thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthefenceandalmostgothislegcaught

\noindent
\textbf{filler.......................text} 
\textbackslash thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthefenceandalmostgothislegcaught

\noindent
\textbf{filler.......................text} 
\textbackslash thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthefenceandalmostgo\-thislegcaught % <==============
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

As you can see the hyphenation in the first sentence (without textbackslash) is okay.

The second sentence is only okay, because I deleted one blank in the filler text. Well, it is (nearly perfect (1.42pt too wide you can ignore, you can not see it on the screenshot, right?).

The third sentence is ugly, because it goes into the margin (4.62pt too wide). The added backslash needs place and the automatic did not hyphenate at the hyphenate mark before (see red arrow marked with 1 in the screenshot) ...

The forth sentence is also ugly, because I added an rule breaking manually hyphenating point with `\-` after the `o` (see red arrow in image, marked with 2).

To summarize:

1. Hyphenation works with package `fontenc` and option `T1` (I would use package `microtype` too).
2. You can use command `\hyphenation{}` to define special words with correct hyphenating.
3. You can always add manual hyphenating points with `\-` in your text.
4. Hyphenating word with special characters (`\, ä, ö, ü, ß, ê, -, ...` can be problematic, but you can use manual added hyphenation points ...

Answer (score 1):

Hyphenation is inhibited past a font change. The LaTeX kernel has

```
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textbackslash}{OMS}
```

and `omsenc.def` has

```
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textbackslash}{OMS}{110}        % "6E
```

which means that `\textbackslash` uses the `OMS` font, which is different from the text font. You can use `\allowbreaks` as defined by `babel`, which adds an unbreakable zero skip. Here I use `\providecommand` so a previous definition by `babel` would not be overwritten.

An alternative is to use the T1 encoding, where the backslash is a character in the same text font.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}  %  enables normal as well as tt text to be hyphenated
\hyphenation{the-quick-brown-fox-jumped-over-the-fence-and-al-most-got-his-leg-caught}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\allowhyphens}{\ifvmode\else\nobreak\hskip\z@skip\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
\textbf{filler.......................text} thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthefenceandalmostgothislegcaught

\noindent
\textbf{filler.......................text} \textbackslash thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthefenceandalmostgothislegcaught

\noindent
\textbf{filler.......................text} \textbackslash\allowhyphens thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthefenceandalmostgothislegcaught

\noindent
\textbf{filler.......................text} \texttt{thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthefenceandalmostgothislegcaught}

\noindent
\textbf{filler.......................text} \texttt{\textbackslash thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthefenceandalmostgothislegcaught}

\noindent
\textbf{filler.......................text} \texttt{\textbackslash\allowhyphens thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthefenceandalmostgothislegcaught}

\end{document}
```

[image]